# Python3.5 tk package showing error

Tags: python, python-3.5

While installing Python3.5-tk package I am getting this error. I am not sure what i am doing wrong.

```
$sudo apt-get install python3-tk

The following NEW packages will be installed:
  python3-tk
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 585 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/42.2 kB of archives.
After this operation, 247 kB of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 400408 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../python3-tk_3.5.3-1ubuntu1~14.04.york1.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python3-tk:amd64 (3.5.3-1ubuntu1~14.04.york1.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-tk_3.5.3-1ubuntu1~14.04.york1.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload/_tkinter.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so', which is also in package libpython3.5-tk:amd64 3.5.2-1~trusty1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-tk_3.5.3-1ubuntu1~14.04.york1.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

So what i am doing wrong here ? Please help

Comment: python is shipped with `tk` installed

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install python-support
sudo update-python-modules -a
sudo apt-get install python3-tk
```